# Why WireMock says that the Request not matches? Spring cloud contract

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

Wiremock logs that the following request not matches:

```
    WireMock                                 : Request was not matched:
{
  "url" : "/api/accounts?username=defaultuser",
  "absoluteUrl" : "http://localhost:11651/api/accounts?username=defaultuser",
  "method" : "GET",
  "clientIp" : "127.0.0.1",
  "headers" : {
    "authorization" : "bearer test123",
    "accept" : "application/json, application/*+json",
    "user-agent" : "Java/1.8.0_121",
    "host" : "localhost:11651",
    "connection" : "keep-alive"
  },
  "cookies" : { },
  "browserProxyRequest" : false,
  "loggedDate" : 1500711718016,
  "bodyAsBase64" : "",
  "body" : "",
  "loggedDateString" : "2017-07-22T08:21:58Z"
}
Closest match:
{
  "urlPath" : "/api/accounts",
  "method" : "GET",
  "headers" : {
    "authorization" : {
      "matches" : "^bearer"
    },
    "accept" : {
      "equalTo" : "application/json, application/*+json"
    },
    "user-agent" : {
      "equalTo" : "Java/1.8.0_121"
    },
    "host" : {
      "matches" : "^localhost:[0-9]{5}"
    },
    "connection" : {
      "equalTo" : "keep-alive"
    }
  },
  "queryParameters" : {
    "username" : {
      "matches" : "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    }
  }
}
```

Is the problem because of the difference of url and urlPath?
I also tried to specify absoluteUrl in the Contract. but it is ignored. I guess because it is not defined in Contract DSL.

The request side of the contract looks like this:

```
request{
        method 'GET'
        url('/api/accounts'){
            queryParameters {
                parameter('username', $(consumer(regex('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$')), producer('defaultuser')))
            }
        }
        headers {
            header('authorization', $(consumer(regex('^bearer')), producer(execute('authClientBearer()'))))
            header('accept', $(consumer('application/json, application/*+json')))
            header('user-agent', $(consumer('Java/1.8.0_121')))
            header('host', $(consumer(regex('^localhost:[0-9]{5}'))))
            header('connection', $(consumer('keep-alive')))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that you're matches for authorization header is wrong. You should end it with.*

Comment: I changed it. But is still not matched.

Comment: In the sent request try adding / at the end before the query parameters. If that doesnt work you can alter the contract sequentially and monitor what is not matched. In other words do a simple get too the URL, then add query parameters and then headers.

Comment: I'll try. I also have a second Contract with the same url but with an email query parameter. Is it possible that WireMock makes only decision based on the url? So if I have two Contracts with the same url but different query parameter it is not able to choose the correct one?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. It rings a bell about the missing / at the end of the url

Comment: Yes was because of the missing "/" on the end of the url! Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to write an answer? So I can mark this question as answered. Or should I do?

Comment: I've written the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out to be a missing / at the end of the URL in the contract/stub

Answer (score 3):

Not directly related to the question but for all who came here from Google:

In my case I was in the wrong scenario state.

More about scenario states here: http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same problem, maybe it's about your problem:
JSON configuration for matching mvcMock example:

```
"request": {
"urlPath": "/hello?name=pavel",
"method": "GET",
 ..
           }
```

And you can see in log:
"/hello?name=pavel" | "/hello?name=pavel" - URL does not match

This is correct.
You have to change:

```
"request": {
    "urlPath": "/hello",
    "method": "GET",
"queryParameters": {
  "name": {
    "equalTo": "pavel"
  }
},
      .. 
      }
```